# Synchronizing audio and video when streaming in Python

Tags: python, opencv, streaming, pyaudio

I have the following code:

receiver side:

```
import cv2
import zmq
import socket
import pyaudio
import wave
import numpy as np
import threading


def recv_video_stream():
    context = zmq.Context()
    footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    footage_socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5554')
    footage_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')

    while True:
            img = footage_socket.recv_pyobj()
            if type(img) != list:
                npimg = np.frombuffer(img, dtype=np.uint8)
                source = cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1)
                cv2.imshow("image", source)
                cv2.waitKey(30)
            else:
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break


def recv_audio_stream():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5003))
    s.listen(10)
    client, addrr = s.accept()
    wf = wave.open('video.wav','rb')
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    print(wf.getframerate())
    CHUNK = 4096
    stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                    channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                    rate=wf.getframerate(),
                    output=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    while True:
        data = client.recv(1024*4)
        if data != b'':
            stream.write(data)
        else:
            break


t1 = threading.Thread(target=recv_video_stream, args=())
t2 = threading.Thread(target=recv_audio_stream, args=())
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

sender side:

```
import cv2
import zmq
import threading
import pyaudio
import socket
import wave





def video_stream():
    context = zmq.Context()
    footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    footage_socket.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5554')

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

    while True:
        grabbed, frame = cap.read()# grab the current frame
        if grabbed == True:
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (500, 300))  # resize the frame
            encoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            footage_socket.send_pyobj(buffer)
            cv2.waitKey(30)
        else:
            footage_socket.send_pyobj(([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]))
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break


def audio_stream():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 5003))
    CHUNK = 1024
    wf = wave.open("video.wav", 'rb')

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                    channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                    rate=wf.getframerate(),
                    input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    while True:
        data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
        if data != b'':
            s.send(data)
        else:
            break


t1 = threading.Thread(target=video_stream, args=())
t2 = threading.Thread(target=audio_stream, args=())
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

As you can see, I'm trying to sync the audio and video (given the audio .wav file and the video .mp4 file for example).
The problem is that I've tried different parameters in "cv2.waitKey(param)", but none of them managed to really create the sync effect.
Does anyone know a good way to find what param should I use to make sure it'll work with different videos and different fps?